# System Out of Memory Exception When Using String.Join

Tags: c#, arrays, string, linq

I have this simple code:

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(1, 100000000).ToArray();
var range = string.Join("", result);
```

What I am trying to do is generate all digits on a range of (`1 to 10^8`) or (`1 to 100000000`)

So in order to do that, I use Enumerable.Range but I get an exeption on the second line of my code which is joining them after the range was made.

I get:

```
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
```

I need to get:

```
1234567891011121314... and so on. (without space)
```

Any idea why?

Comment: See the top 2 answers. Let me know if this is **not** a duplicate and I'll reopen

Comment: _"my largest input is 10^8"_ -- largest input for what? What is it you're actually trying to do? On the face of it, the code you posted is just plain ridiculous. In what scenario is it useful to have a string made up of 100 million different numbers concatenated together? What is it that you're _trying_ to do?

Comment: _"I tried other solutions on SO but this case is different"_ -- other solutions to what? What did you try? Why is your case different?

Comment: I edited my question on what I want to do and the output I am expecting.

Comment: As the answer says, no single object in a .Net program may be over 2GB. Joining every number from `1` to `10^8` exceeds that limit, hence the `OutOfMemoryException`.

Comment: If the duplicate is not enough to help you, you should probably open a new question and ask about what you actually want to do. Typically, a string in program memory is just dead weight unless it is *used* somewhere (print, write to file, compute something). If you explain your usage, you may get suggestions on what to do *instead of* creating a single string.